# Converting a PNG image to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a PNG file which when I convert the image to a numpy array, it is of the format that is 184 x 184 x 4. The image is 184 by 184 and each pixel is in RGBA format and hence the 3D array.

This a B&W image and the pixels are either [255, 255, 255, 255] or [0, 0, 0, 255].

I want to convert this to a 184 x 184 2D array where the pixels are now either 1 or 0, depending upon if it is [255, 255, 255, 255] or [0, 0, 0, 255].

Any ideas how to do a straightforward conversion of this.

Answer (score 1):

There would be several ways to do the comparison to give us a `boolean array` and then, we just need to convert to `int array` with type conversion. So, for the comparison, one simple way would be to compare against `255` and check for `ALL` matches along the last axis. This would correspond to checking for `[255, 255, 255, 255]`. Thus, one approach would be like so -

```
((arr == 255).all(-1)).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [301]: arr
Out[301]: 
array([[[255, 255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255]],

       [[  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255]]])

In [302]: ((arr == 255).all(-1)).astype(int)
Out[302]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are really only two values in the array as you say, simply scale and return one of the dimensions:

```
(arr[:,:,0] / 255).astype(int)
```